# Opendistro elasticsearch, no permissions for [ ] and User [name=admin, roles=[admin]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I try to run this command on elasticsearch server but i get error for permission.

I use opendistro for elasticsearch

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'securitytenant: Private' -u admin --insecure -d '{
"index" : {
    "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}'
```

> {“error”:{“root_cause”:[{“type”:“security_exception”,“reason”:“no
>   permissions for [ ] and User [name=admin, roles=[admin],
>   requestedTenant=Private]”}],“type”:“security_exception”,“reason”:“no
>   permissions for [ ] and User [name=admin, roles=[admin],
>   requestedTenant=Private]”},“status”:403}

I tried also with out securitytenant but with the same error permission.

Other command's they run with success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem after migrating to opendistro with elasticsearch 7.

I did test creating new roles and cluster/index permissions, but didn't works.

Finally, what I did is `curl` a more specific url, specifying the index pattern, something like ...

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_settings?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"number_of_replicas": 0}' --insecure -u admin:...
```

And it works XD.

Acknowledge true.

Try with that.

Good look.

Comment: thanks :) i will test if is working also with just * :P regards ;)